# CKFinder 2: "File browser is disabled for security reasons"

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

This is so frustrating.  Using CKFinder v2, and get that dialog box every time the page loads.  I've Googled for an hour and have yet to find a definitive answer for it other than the developer saying in an old forum post (on a site that is now closed to new posts), "you should read the developer docs."  Yeah that's real useful.  I've done that.

Since we aren't using PHP or .NET, I'm doing what the v3 docs said and am using v2, the JavaScript Integration method.  This is the code from their example page:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ColdFusion/Integration/JavaScript

```
var finder = new CKFinder();
finder.basePath = '/ckfinder/';
finder.create();
```

I know it loads a config.js file, but that file doesn't say anything about it either; and I've looked at the API docs and found nothing about it as well.

The widget loads up just fine but without the file browser, it's fairly useless for our purposes.  We will be integrating it into CKEditor and purchasing a commercial license for it IF we can get it to work.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score -2):

It turns out it has to do with a function called `CheckAuthentication()`, which somehow runs under whichever "integration" method you downloaded -- could be `PHP`, `ASP`, `ColdFusion`, etc.

In my case (`ColdFusion`), I had to go into `config.cfm` and add code in there to make it return `true` (checking for proper authentication).